# How to add card in column in flutter android

Tags: flutter

I want to add Card into column in my app. I have added card into a container. code given below

```html
  body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
        height: 183,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5,
          shadowColor: Colors.blue,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: Column(.....),
        ), //card
      ), //Container
```

Please tell me how to add card into column

Comment: please make your question clear? Column into card or Card in column ? What is desired ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution of your problem is use List in your app to show CardView in vertical form.

```
   ListView.builder(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
itemCount: 10,
   itemBuilder:(context, position) {
  return Card (
  Child: Text("Hello Flutter"))}
    )
```

This is code for you problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding Card in a column

```
Column(
  children: const <Widget>[
  Card(), //card1
  Card(), //card2
])
```